# Alter Table based on duplicate values in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to change the type to be the same for the same item. For example my table looks like this:

```
  item | type
   A   |  1  
   B   |  2  
   A   |  3   
   C   |  4  
   B   |  5   
   A   |  6
```

Desired output:

```
  item | type
   A   |  1  
   B   |  2  
   A   |  1   
   C   |  3  
   B   |  2   
   A   |  1
```

Comment: Right... but which one is the correct type, for example, for `A`? Is it `1`, `3`, or `6`? How did you decide the "chosen one" was `1`?

Comment: @TheImpaler say that's the self-incrementing key in the first example table. I just want a query to group the rows in the item column and select the first instance of the type.

Comment: No such thing as "the first row". Database tables don't have order. You can pick the **smallest**, or the **biggest**, or something else.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the value to the *smallest*:

```
update t
    set t.type = t2.min_type
    from (select t2.item, min(type) as min_type
          from t t2
          group by t2.item
         ) t2;
```

If you have a column that specifies the ordering, you can phrase this as:

```
update t
    set t.type = t2.type
    from (select distinct on (t2.item) t2.item, t2.type
          from t t2
          order by t2.item, t2.?
         ) t2;
```

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "first" row unless a column specifically contains this information.